# Calculation of the CPTs in a Dynamic Bayesian Network

Tags: bayesian-networks

I am trying to figure out how to build my DBN (with pyAgrum), and I am a bit confused. Let us say I have the network on the next figure.

I am interested in the variable $B$. At each time $t$, I am reading the data $A_t$, $B_t$, $C_t$ and $D_t$ from my sensors to find the likelyhood of $B_{t+1}$.  An then, at time $t+1$ , I start again with the data from the sensors. Is it the correct way to proceed?

Moreover, I do not know the CPTs (Conditional Probability Table) for my DBN (it's actually one thing I want to find), can we update as time progresses the values of the CPTs?

It's one thing I'm not sure with DBN, are the CPTs fixed, or do they change over time?

Thanks in advance for your clarification

[image: Example of Dynamic Bayesian Network]